# Загрузка файла из каталога

Tags: загрузка, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Есть текстовый файл с данными. Он лежит в папке с exe-шником. Как мне его загрузить именно оттуда? А то приходится кидать его в корень HDD для проверки.
VS2012

**Ответ:**
Нашёл функцию `GetCurrentDirectory(int iBufferSize, LPSTR Buffer)`, если кому надо будет =)

Comment: А разве просто указать имя файла (без пути) не получается?

Comment: Нашёл функцию GetCurrentDirectory(int iBufferSize, LPSTR Buffer)
если кому надо будет =)

Comment: GetCurrentDirectory может преподнести иногда сюрпризы. Причем очень необычные. К примеру, если использовать диалог для открытия/сохранения файлов, то он изменяет текущий каталог. И это даже если никакой файл не открыли - просто открыли диалог и перешли в другой каталог.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну для начала в функции открытия файла указываете просто имя файла которое хотите открыть и она откроет файл в том же каталоге в котором находится ваш экзешник.
Но у VS есть кое какая придурь. Если вы будете запускать программу самим экзешником то она норм откроет файл который лежит рядом с вашим экзешником. Но если вы будете запускать вашу программу из самой VS то ваш файл должен лежать не в папке с экзешником Debug, а в главной папки самого проекта.
Так что выбирайте куда вам файл положить для проверки и как вы будете проверять.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, попробую. =)
Кстати да, придурь есть. К примеру при запуске приложения из VS мне выдает run-time check #0, а если запускать на прямую, то всё норм.

Comment: Да, всё работает. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В main (или _tmain, зависит от версии) есть два параметра - argv и argc. В них храниться список входных параметров и их количество. Но дело в том, что под нулевым номером хранится путь+имя Вашего exe файла. Дальше все зависит от того, какую библиотеку используете, но в самом простом случае, можно скопировать все до последнего слеша и добавить имя Вашего файла.

```
std::string s(argv[0]);
std::string f = s.substr(0, s.find_last_of("\\/") + 1) + "Your file.txt;
```

**upd**

Для более правильного определения имени, [рекомендуется](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060515-07/?p=31203) использовать [GetModuleFileName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea)

Comment: @KoVadim "Но дело в том, что под нулевым номером хранится путь+имя Вашего exe файла." -- это что, в microsoft придумали? У меня виндов под рукой нет, проверить не могу. В unix-like'ах там лежит первое слово команды. При наличии директории екзешника в `%path%` там никакого пути, как я думаю, может и не лежать. Да и расширения `.exe` тоже может не быть.

Comment: в линуске дело немного по другому обстоит. Там возможен вариант, когда имя файла с путем нельзя получить (ну кроме хаков). [Вот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050961/is-argv0-name-of-executable-an-accepted-standard-or-just-a-common-conventi) подборочка и обсуждений.

Comment: @KoVadim Не стал я читать эти обсуждения. Программу, печатающую argv[0] оттранслировал (a.exe) и поместил в `~/.wine/drive_c/windows`. Затем `wine cmd.exe`, в ней набрал команду `a` и получил ответ `а`, но никак не `c:\windows\a.exe`. Думаю, что в родных виндах будет точно так же.

Comment: а давайте я в машину залью авиационный бензин и буду утверждать, что он портит двигатель.

Comment: @KoVadim Не понял. Но -- давайте (в России авиационный бензин вроде не производится -- поршневых самолётов осталось очень мало, и заводы закрыты-перепрофилированы).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! =)

Answer (score 0):

`ExtractFilePath(Application->ExeName) + fileName` - Такая конструкция употребляется в C++Builder. В результате возвращается `AnsiString` с полным путем к файлу.

Comment: да, вот только у ТС VS2012. А там это не будет работать.